# How to provide database configuration settings in code-first Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am not using `localdb` or `./sqlexpress` I have to use server name

```
MSOLDEV03\SQL2012
```

Here is my code for generating database; when I run I get a `SqlConnection` error "server not found":

```
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

I used command

```
 Enable-Migrations
```

this command makes migration folder but does not generate database on my SQL Server instance `MSOLDEV03\SQL2012`

Then I tried to run this code

```
  using (var db = new BloggingContext())
  {
            db.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Name = "Another Blog " });
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var blog in db.Blogs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blog.Name);
            }
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Still not generate database but gives error connection to SQL Server not found.

Here is my `app.config` file contains no sql connection

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
          type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context class constructor, you can give the key like:

```
public BloggingContext() : base("name=BloggingContextKey")
        {

        }
```

and then give this key a value in your configuration file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BloggingContextKey" connectionString="Data Source=<Your server>; Initial Catalog=<Database>;user=<user>;pwd=<password>;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: but Initial Catalog=<Database> i have to create database there is no existing database

Comment: Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName BloggingContextKey -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ConnectionStringName BloggingContextKey but gives error context BloggingContextKey not found

Comment: how to give server name in passing parameters in package manager console along with enable migrations\

Comment: In code first, first you define classes i.e. your business model. Database will be created automatically when you first time use BloggingContext.

Comment: ANSWERS: Initial Catalog=<Database NAME TO CREATE>

Comment: Server name will be same as you mentioned "MSOLDEV03\SQL2012",<Database>  - any name you want for your database.